ngrok URL not responding with the value of challenge parameter
I am trying to build a slack AI APP using https://github.com/daveebbelaar/langchain-experiments this as my base I was using ngrok to generate a url for the event subscription but i am getting the error Your URL didn't respond with the value of the challenge parameter.
My url ends with ngrok-free.app what should i do to make it work?
I tried creating new urls at different ports update the api tokens for open ai / slack bot token user id token

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

The url ending in "ngrok-free.app" should not make a difference here.
As I understand, the slack_bolt python middleware should handle the URL challenge request.
See https://github.com/daveebbelaar/langchain-experiments/blob/main/slack/app.py
Make sure that you are adding the /slack/events
at the end of your ngrok URL when adding it to your Slack App per the instructions (step 3):
https://github.com/daveebbelaar/langchain-experiments/tree/main/slack

https://...ngrok-free.app/slack/events

You can verify if the challenge request is making it to your ngrok Agent by going to the Web Inspection Interface at http://localhost:4040 (as shown in the ngrok Agent GUI).
[Example of a challenge request making it to the ngrok Agent][1]
[1]: https://i.sstatic.net/xJjQeGiI.png
The instructions say to run ngrok forwarding to port 5000 upstream to the app.
Try connecting to the flask app at http://localhost:5000/slack/events from a browser to verify that you are getting any response from the app, before running ngrok.
